# CASE WHEN mySQL keeps getting error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am trying to use the CASE statement, but I keep getting a syntax error. I have followed the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) but I cannot seem to get rid of this syntax error:
query:

```
SELECT students.firstname, students.lastname, students.tnumber, grades.tnumber 
FROM students, grades 
CASE WHEN grades.tnumber=students.tnumber AND grades.courseid='CSC2110' AND (grades.Grade='A' OR grades.Grade='B' OR grades.Grade='C')THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
```

error:

`error executing query. MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN grades.tnumber=students.tnumber AND grades.courseid='CSC2110' A' at line 1`

Ignore the tables and select statements. I am more concerned are checking the syntax of my CASE statement and why it is throwing an error.

Comment: You should show some sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't completely clear what you want the `CASE` expression to do, but it appears that it should be in the `SELECT` list.  I also moved the join condition, which strangely appeared in the `CASE` expression, to the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT students.firstname,
       students.lastname,
       students.tnumber,
       grades.tnumber,
       CASE WHEN grades.courseid = 'CSC2110' AND
                 (grades.Grade='A' OR grades.Grade='B' OR grades.Grade='C')
            THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS someColumn
FROM students
INNER JOIN grades
    ON grades.tnumber = students.tnumber
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense but I am still getting a syntax error

Comment: There was a missing comma.  Did you catch it?

Comment: caught it. Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one mate, using `proper` and `readable` syntax:

```
SELECT
    s.tnumber, s.firstname, s.lastname, 
    IF (
    -- condition
        grades.Grade = 'A' OR grades.Grade = 'B' OR grades.Grade = 'C',
    -- if true
        'YES',
    -- else
        'NO'
    ) `status`
FROM
    students s
    INNER JOIN grades g ON g.tnumber = s.tnumber
WHERE grades.courseid = 'CSC2110';
```

**Note**

- You can where that I have included a `WHERE` section where you can easily reuse this code with other `courseid`
- I also added a `suggested` format when presenting data which is for people, always put the `id` code infront
- One more point is that, by using a `proper` format, it help you and others to `understand` your code